# How to get a total value from a loop result for integers in php. without Javascript of Jquery

Tags: php, loops, while-loop, logic

how to add a total of the numbers displayed as an integer from a loop. the loop result is not an increment. here is the problem.

```
<?php
    $i = 0;
    $num =1;

    while($i<=4){

     echo $num;
      $i++;
    }
 echo $num;
   ?>
```

So the result is something like this.

```
1 1 1 1
```

so my problem is how can i total the result which should be 4, and save it in a variable without incrementing. and even more confusing is. how to do the same when the value of $num is dynamic. Thank you very much. in advance

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do???

Comment: https://eval.in/108799 ?

Comment: @ethan I wanted the $num value to remain the same(or dynamic) througout the loop, and at the end or outside the loop I wanted the total values of the $num displayed from the loop. but thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make an array then sum them:

```
<?php
    $i = 0;
    $num =1;

    while($i<=4){

     $nums[] = $num;
      $i++;
    }
    echo array_sum($nums); //Outputs 5
?>
```

*This assumes that `$num` is always numeric.*

Comment: You're welcome.  Also, as a site note, I notice that you don't seem to accept answers.  This is vital because it allows for future visitors with a similar question to find the answer fast and easily and lets people know that one of the answers actually did work.  You can read more about it here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: thanks again. I will get into the habit accepting the answers, I have accepted yours as it was just what I needed. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could just iterate an output variable, based on the value of $num.  Like so:

```
<?php
$num = 1; // or 2, or 3, or 4 or whatever
$output = 0;
for ($i=0; $i<=4; $i++) {
    $output += $num;
}
echo $output;
?>
```